# Is there a field $k$ in which $x^3+3$ has double roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots

I am doing a problem in which I am looking at the polynomial $x^3+3$ in a field $k$. I have separated my answer in three cases:

1. $x^3+3$ has no roots in $k$
2. $x^3+3$ has exactly one root in $k$
3. $x^3+3$ has three roots in $k$

For the last case, however, I came across a question. Is it possible that $x^3+3$ has a double (or even triple) root in a field $k$?. If I take "easy" fields such as $\mathbb{C}$ then I know it's not the case, but perhaps in some more complicated ones it happens. I have been thinking about finite fields for example but didn't find any in which this happens. Can someone help me find me a field $k$ of this form, or show me that it cannot exist?

Comment: The only such fields are the ones where $3=0.$ No double roots.

Comment: It will never happen in characteristic zero. Generally $f$ has a repeated root if and only if $\gcd(f, f') \ne 1$, ie iff $\gcd(x^3 + 3, 3x^2) \ne 1$, ie iff $x \mid x^3 + 3$, ie iff $x \mid 3$. So it has a repeated root in any field of characteristic $3$. (Can you see what the root is?)

Comment: A double root is a root of the derivative, but the derivative here is $3x^2,$ which, if $3\neq 0,$ can only be $0$. But if $0$ is a double root, then $3=0^3+3=0$.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think this should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score -1):

The discriminant of $x^3+3$ is $\Delta=-27\cdot 3^2$. If there is a repeated root, then $\Delta=0$, so in this field $3^5=0$ and hence $3=0$. The converse is clearly true, so the result is any field $k$ with characteristic $3$.

Comment: Could the down-voter explain?

Comment: Requiring the knowledge about the discriminant of a cubic equation is overkill. Izaak's and Thomas' comments above are sufficient.